# Loading binary file with webpack and converting to Blob

Tags: webpack, jszip

I have a `<input id=file-chooser" type="file"/>` control that I allow a user to upload a .zip file with and I then hand that off to [jszip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) for further processing.

I am trying to test this by loading a local .zip test file in webpack, converting to a Blob, and then manually firing the `change` event with the content of the file.

jszip is complaining that the zip file is not valid and I think I am messing something up on the conversion.

I've tried:

```
// Load file at webpack compilation time
const zipFileRaw = require("raw-loader!../test.zip");

// Convert to ArrayBuffer
const bytes = new Uint8Array(zipFileRaw.length);
for (var i = 0; i < zipFileRaw.length; ++i) {
  bytes[i] = zipFileRaw.charCodeAt(i);
}

// Construct a 'change' event with file Blob
const file = new Blob(bytes, { type: "application/zip" });
file.name = "test.zip";
const event = { type: "change", target: { files: [file] } };

// Fire the event
$("#file-chooser").trigger(event);
```

Firing the event works and my event handler is called.  In the event handler for the `change` event I call `jsZip.loadAsync(file)` and I get:

> Error: Can't find end of central directory : is this a zip file ?

Comment: how is this ember related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting this to work by using the url-loader along with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20151856/626911) for converting base64 to a Blob.

```
// Load file at webpack compilation time
const zipFileRaw: string = require("url-loader!../test.zip");
const [match, contentType, base64] = zipFileRaw.match(/^data:(.+);base64,(.*)$/);

// Convert the base64 to a Blob
// Souce: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20151856/626911
const file = base64toBlob(base64, contentType);

// Construct a 'change' event with file Blob
const event: any = { type: "change", target: { files: [file] } };

// Fire the event
$("#file-chooser").trigger(event);
```